Linux driver support for Terratect T5 usb tuner
Hi I have a Terrate T5 usb tuner (https://www.terratec.de/details.php?artnr=10908&lang=en)
and I am trying to get it to work under ubuntu 24.04.
When I plug it to a usb port and run lsusb I get
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 0ccd:10b7 TerraTec Electronic GmbH TERRATEC T5 Rev.2

If I run usb-devices I get
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=13 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 19 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0ccd ProdID=10b7 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=TERRATEC
S:  Product=TERRATEC T5 Rev.2
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=84(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=85(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=86(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=125us

which if I am reading it correctly ubuntu does not load any drivers for it.
I check the 0ccd:10b7 and it does not seem to be yet supported in current kernel in ubuntu 24.04 (or so I think) (https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices and http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)
So far I tried loading similar modules using modprobe and then trying to force a driver to be used (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442833/how-to-force-driver-to-device-match-in-linux) by using the command below
echo "0ccd 10b7" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/XXXXXX/new_id

but no matter what I do I can not get any driver to be assigned to the tuner.
So I have to ask.

Does someone knows why I can not force a driver to be used for my usb tuner? I understand that even if I get a driver to be assigned to the usb tuner this might of course no work at all after but I though to give it a shot first anyway.

Is there a procedure (ubuntu or elsewhere) that I can make where I can request my usb to be
supported in the future? I already tried contacting terratec but I
have yet to get and answer from them.

Any other ideas about how to make my usb tuner to work under ubuntu?


Thanks

No driver, no joy. Terratec does not provide any Linux drivers. I'm using a Sundtek tuner since ages on my devices. They work really good.

thanks but if they do not provide why there are other sticks from terratec that work under linux? maybe they did in the past?

they changed the device number. 00ac 00a9 and 00d7 worked back in 2010-ish.  this is the best I could find: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=222542 (2016 so old)

thanks @Rinzwind. I believe I already have the modules that mentions in that article loaded but I can not assign a driver to the usb stick. If they just change the device number should I be able to make it work if I manage to assign the correct driver or is it more complicate than that?

nope. new device numbers means the chipset changed. and with terratec it means a complete new one.

thanks @Rinzwind. I will return the card back next working day to get my money back. This card is crap it does not even have drivers for windows 10/11. It only supports up to windows 7 which is stop support many years ago and therefore I can not even test it. Although I bought it new from a computer shop is probably eol product.

20 years of History in the PCTV area:

Terratec is out of business for a long time, they only exist as branding nowadays so they won't develop their own devices. Terratec once was famous for bringing a USB DVB-T tuner to the market, the tuner was developed by a physics student back then, a single engineer he offered the tuner to Terratec.
Hauppauge U.S. is still active but cycled employees in engineering over the years
Hauppauge Germany went bankrupt
PCTV Systems got acquired by Hauppauge and laid off all the people in Germany
Pinnacle PCTV changed the company name to PCTV Systems, Pinnacle is a larger company they didn't see that it makes sense to continue.
Miro Media PCTV (early 2000s), they brought the brooktree bt878 tuner to the market got acquired by Pinnacle.
Sundtek is still active with the original staff (the owner worked in the R&D pre-supply chain for some products for Hauppauge, Terratec and Pinnacle almost 2 decades ago)

Up to date Linux drivers are only available from Sundtek.
